# when i set div style overflow is scroll, justify-content is flex-start, flex layout wrap is incorrect

Tags: css, flexbox, overflow

If I set #main.overflow is none, I get what I want.

And if I set #main.overflow is scroll, which is not what I want, the last element is broken by error.

Why do scroll bars cause Flex layout errors?

right result

```css
  * {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  #main {
    overflow: none;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #321;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    padding: 10px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
  }
  .el {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 5px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="el"></div>
  <div class="el"></div>
  <div class="el"></div>
</div>
```

incorrect result

```css
  * {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  #main {
    overflow: scroll;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #321;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    padding: 10px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
  }
  .el {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 5px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="el"></div>
  <div class="el"></div>
  <div class="el"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is: The scrollbars take up space inside the div. If you force them to render by setting `overflow: scroll` you take up some of the space inside the flexbox and `flex: wrap` property causes the content to wrap.

Your `main` flexbox can handle content of **180px** width*.

The content width is also exactly **180px****

This allows no space for the scrollbars and the content ends up wrapping onto the next line.

There is a [deprecated property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow): `overflow: overlay` which causes the scrollbars to not take up space but it has very limited support and is deprecated so I would not recommend using it.

---

*Because the width is set to **200px** which includes **10px** padding on each side. The `box-sizing: border-box` property makes it so the [padding is included in the height and width calculation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

**Each `el` has 60px width including the margin on both sides.

Comment: I need border-box. In fact, I used it in the Electron App. Plan 1 is really easy to use.Thank you. I am continuing to check whether electron will pack in the browser. If so, this scheme is perfect.